# How can I search for post's 'title','content'&'meta_query' without WP_Query 's'?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have written a search query in wordpress that searches for 'post_title', 'post_content' & 'meta_query'. Instead of using WP_Query Search 's' parameter, can I use WP_Query's 'post' & 'meta_query' related parameters combine with 'OR' so that search query matches the 'post_title' and 'post_content' by passing only concerned parameters of WP_Query? OR is there a way to write query manually with $wpdb like below:

```
global $wpdb;
$query= "SELECT wp_dxwe_posts.* FROM `wp_posts` WHERE 
(wp_posts.post_status IN ('$status_array') AND
wp_posts.post_type='messages') AND 
(wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR wp_posts.post_content 
LIKE '%$keyword%') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key == 'my_meta_key' AND 
wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$keyword%') ";

$my_query = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Can any one please tell me how? Thanks in advance.

I am getting the following MySql result query:

```
  SELECT * FROM `wp_dxwe_posts` wp 
INNER JOIN `wp_dxwe_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`) 
WHERE wp.`post_status` IN ('publish,pending,draft') 
AND wp.`post_type`='messages'
AND (wp.`post_title` LIKE '%prasad%' OR 
wp.`post_content` LIKE '%prasad%') 
    AND wm.`meta_key` = 'inistitute_name' 
    AND wm.`meta_value` LIKE '%some_institute_name%'
```

Comment: your custom query will works... what problem you are facing?

Comment: @Happy Coding, First, thanks for your quick reply. When I run that query in PhpMyAdmin then it gives me error like "#1054 - Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause'"

Comment: You have to indicate what you mean with *doesn't work*.  What is the current problem now that you have the new sql result query?

Answer (score -1):

Use custom query in following way :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` wp 
    INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`) 
        WHERE wp.`post_status` IN ('$status_array') 
        AND wp.`post_type`='messages'
        AND (wp.`post_title` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
wp.`post_content` LIKE '%$keyword%') 
        AND wm.`meta_key` = 'my_meta_key' 
        AND wm.`meta_value` LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Comment: Why does this work? Code-only answers are not very helpful.  Further, it would be nice if you actually formatted this to be a bit more readable...

Comment: @cale_b, I have tried it but Its not working. it is giving the result which am adding in my question above.

Comment: @prasadchinthala clarify what you want to do with that query. Acc. to your comments it giving the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause".. i provided the custom query. Now what problem you are facing

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got it by using only 'WP_Query'. I felt difficulty by using custom query like above takes more time and complicated so I used the traditional one i.e. WP_Query.